Scrape average price from Bricklink
I'm trying to make a  google sheet which monitors the average price of certain figures on Bricklink, and started with a code that chatgpt gave me. The sheet would have dates in the A column and from the B column the scraped average prices to certain figures.
my code right now (with comments from chatgpt):
function scrapeMultipleWebsites() {
    // Array of URLs to scrape numbers from
    const urls = [
        "https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?M=sw1363&ColorID=0",
        "https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?M=sw1325&ColorID=0",
        "https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?M=sw1377&ColorID=0",
        // Add up to 20 URLs in total 
    ];
    
    // Regular expression to extract numbers (adjust this if needed for each URL)
    const regex = /<TD>Avg Price:<\/TD><TD><B>HUF&nbsp;[0-9]*,\d+.\d+/;
    

    // Target Sheet
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("'24 SW Figure price monitor"); // Update sheet name
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    const nextRow = Math.max(3, lastRow + 1); // Ensure the script starts writing from Row 3

    // Add current date in Column A
    const currentDate = new Date();
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(currentDate);

    // Loop through URLs and scrape numbers
    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[i]).getContentText();
        const match = html.match(regex);
        Logger.log(match);

        if (match) {
            const number = match[1]; // Extract matched number
            sheet.getRange(nextRow, i + 2).setValue(number); // Start at Column B (index 2)
        } else {
            sheet.getRange(nextRow, i + 2).setValue("N/A"); // If no match, add "N/A"
        }
    }
}

The html looks the same with all bricklink price guide links (see above in the code), so the same regex for all the different links should work in theory. It searches for the simple average price (so not the qty avg) of a new figure in the last 6 months. Since I live in Hungary, a returned value in HUF should look something like this: 12,438.02
Whatever regex I have put in I never got anything but the N/A back. I tried many longer and way more specific regexes as well with no success. In fact I tried so many versions I started to believe the problem might not be with that part. But still, when I tried it with Logger.log(match), it said there were no matches.
Here's an example of a more detailed regex I tried which has only one correct returned value: (nevertheless it didn't help the code finding the price)
/[0-9]*,\d+.\d+(?=<\/B><\/TD><\/TR><TR ALIGN="RIGHT"><TD>Qty Avg Price:<\/TD><TD><B>HUF&nbsp;[0-9]*,\d+.\d+<\/B><\/TD><\/TR><TR ALIGN="RIGHT"><TD>Max Price:<\/TD><TD><B>HUF&nbsp;[0-9]*,\d+.\d+<\/B><\/TD><\/TR><\/TABLE><\/TD><\/TR><\/TABLE><\/TD><TD VALIGN="TOP"><TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="5" CELLSPACING="0"><TR><TD><TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" WIDTH="100%" CLASS="fv"><TR ALIGN="RIGHT"><TD WIDTH="50%">Times Sold:&nbsp;)/
I have tried checkers like regexr.com and regex101.com but there my regexes worked and the correct prices were always found.
(I'm not a very experienced programmer, but I know some things and can learn quickly.)

Using regular expressions to parse HTML for web pages that you don't control is a bad idea. Instead, use a library to parse HTML like cheeriogs.

I would normally agree with that, and there is a way to do it by looping through checking text content, but the usage of tables with no classnames or identifying features means it would be a ton of very specific and fragile selector trees to get to the necessary cells. It's also not really HTML parsing, just looking for text following the phrase "Avg. Price:"

This script contains an API (Free Currency Exchange Rates API) posted on Github that automatically gets the USD currency on the last parameter and then returns it as an object. I also modified your regex syntax based on your needs. It displays all the average prices of a new figure in the last 6 months in HUF currency. You can read more about regex here.
Here's a modified version of your script that should work:
function scrapeMultipleWebsites() {

  const usdJson = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fawazahmed0/currency-api@latest/v1/currencies/usd.json")).getContentText());

  // Array of URLs to scrape numbers from
  const urls = [
    "https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?M=sw1363&ColorID=0",
    "https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?M=sw1325&ColorID=0",
    "https://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?M=sw1377&ColorID=0"
    // Add up to 20 URLs in total 
  ];

  // Regular expression to extract numbers (adjust this if needed for each URL)
  const regex = /<td>Avg Price:<\/td><td><b>US&nbsp;\$(\d+(\.\d+)?)/i;


  // Target Sheet
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("'24 SW Figure price monitor"); // Update sheet name
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const nextRow = Math.max(3, lastRow + 1); // Ensure the script starts writing from Row 3


  // Add current date in Column A
  const currentDate = new Date();
  sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(currentDate);


  // Loop through URLs and scrape numbers
  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[i]).getContentText();
    const match = html.match(regex);
    Logger.log(match);

    if (match) {
      const number = match[1]; // Extract matched number
      sheet.getRange(nextRow, i + 2).setValue((usdJson.usd.huf * number).toFixed(2)); // Start at Column B (index 2)
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(nextRow, i + 2).setValue("N/A"); // If no match, add "N/A"
    }
  }
}


Reference:

exchange-api


Thanks, now it gives back a price, so it works now, but it's in a different exchange rate than what Bricklink uses, so the prices are off.
The main problem of my previous code might been that I didn't realize whenever I look at bricklink I get prices in HUF, but when the code looks at the site it gets USD prices. Is there a way to get the HUF prices in Bricklink's exchage rates? (Like a link that displays them automatically in HUF?)

(Like in the code make it request from Hungary?)

Here's a very simplified version you can try, it does seem to work in regex101 but not sure how it will perform in your implementation: />Avg Price:.+?(HUF[^<]+)/
The idea being:

>Avg Price: Start matching when you hit the text "Avg Price:" as the first thing in a td (to rule out qty avg)
.+? Non-greedy match to consume anything in the way until you hit the part you want
(HUF[^<]+) Capture starting with HUF and take everything up until the table cell closes by only matching non-< characters

Also, commenting above made me realize that might be a better approach for you. If you can get the text content of the page instead of the HTML, you can just use regex to look for the string you want without needing to adjust for HTML tags
